# Is it possible to create a multi-line header in a Vuetify datatable?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to create a table with a multiline header, like in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShrCz.png).

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027979/vuetifyjs-how-to-create-multi-lines-header-in-v-data-table), however the answer does not work. Furthermore, I have looked at the Vuetify documentation and Github issues, but there seems to be no solution.

Would be great if someone could let me know whether something like this is possible and if so how.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out you can simply implement your own categories line above the default headers if you just add `<thead>` in the slot template. Leaving out the `<thead>` puts it underneath.

```
<v-data-table ...>
  <template v-slot:header="props" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Category 1</th>
        <th colspan="3">Category 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: That is great and helps me with what I need. Just a quick note, if you do not have a use for the props and dont need the header text write the slot attribute like so `v-slot:header` without the `="props"`

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use slot="headerCell". Note that the version of Vuetify used here is 1.5.11

Here's a sample that might give you some pointers:

```
<v-data-table
    v-bind:headers="headers"
    v-bind:items="items"
    v-bind:search="search"
    v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"
    hide-actions
    class="elevation-1"
>
  <template slot="headerCell" scope="props">
    <div slot="activator">
      {{ props.header.text }}
    </div>
    <div>
       <span>A</span>
       <span>||</span>
       <span>B</span>
    </div>
    </template>
    <template slot="items" scope="props">
      .....
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

Here's the codepen link : https://codepen.io/nizantz/pen/KYyLOp

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I think my question is not entirely clear, what I want is also to have multiple columns. So below A and B should be columns, which contains different data. Basically I want two header lines, where the first header's col spans over multiple columns in the actual table. Do you know whether this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is Core code

```
<v-data-table :headers="surgeryInformationHeaders" :items="surgeryInformationDesserts" hide-default-footer class="transparent elevation-0 my-4" hide-default-header disable-pagination disable-sort :items-per-page="5">
      <template #header="{ }">
        <thead class="v-data-table-header">
          <tr>
            <th v-for="(h,i) in surgeryInformationHeaders" :key="i" class="text-center parent-header td-border-style" :rowspan="h.children?1:2" :colspan="h.children?h.children.length:1">
              {{ h.text }}
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th v-for="(h1,i1) in getSubHeader(surgeryInformationHeaders)" :key="i1" class="text-center child-header td-border-style">
              {{ h1.text }}
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </template>
      <template #item="props">
        <tr>
          <td v-for="(c,ci) in getRows(props.item)" :key="ci">
            {{ c }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Here's codeopen link https://codepen.io/sunhao1256/pen/MWeZyMe

Comment: And still have the columns sortable?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another sample that might help your case, based on your comment
Note that the data structure needs to be in the right format.(Child elements)

Vue-Template :

```
    <div id="app">
          <v-data-table
          :headers="headersTop"
          :items="tableitems"
          hide-actions
          >
      <template slot="items" scope="props">
        <td>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="[{text:'First Name', value:'fname', sortable:false},
                      {text:'Last Name', value:'lname', sortable:false}
                      ]"
            :items="props.item.name"
            hide-actions                    
          >
            <template slot="items" scope="props">
              <td>{{props.item.fname}}</td>
              <td>{{props.item.lname}}</td>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="[{text:'Country', value:'country', sortable:false},
                      {text:'City', value:'city', sortable:false}
                      ]"
            :items="props.item.geo"
            hide-actions
          >
            <template slot="items" scope="props">
              <td>{{props.item.country}}</td>
              <td>{{props.item.city}}</td>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </td>
      </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data () {
        return {
          pagination: {},
          headersTop:[
            {
              text: 'Name',
              value: 'name',
              sortable: false,
            },
            {
              text: 'Geo',
              value: 'geo',
              sortable: false,
            }
          ],
        tableitems:[{
            name: [{
                fname: 'Dakota',
                lname: 'Rice'
              },
              {
                fname: 'Minerva',
                lname: 'Hooper'
              }],
            geo: [{
                    country: 'Niger',
                    city: 'Oud-Tunrhout',            
                  },
                  {
                    country: 'Curaçao',
                    city: 'Sinaai-Waas',
                  }]
            }]
          }
        }
    })
```

Heres's the codepen link : https://codepen.io/nizantz/pen/rbpNrY

Comment: You can play around with the code and with the right data structure(json format) , you might not need two nested data-tables as in the example. This is just a sample and not the exact solution to your question.